# How to read TStringGrid values and assign them to TEdits

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

I am trying to implement a way to select a person's name from a `TStringGrid` that has values in two rows with two columns. These rows represent names of people and their respective ages. Once a name is selected by clicking on it, I want to fill two `TEdit` fields with the name and age that I selected.

I have been struggling with this and I can only get the entire row as one string, but I need the name and age as separate strings.

I have attached a screenshot to give an idea of what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you for any help.

[image: TStringGrid Screenshot]

Comment: Add code to the question of what you already did and are not happy with.

Comment: Thank you, @RemyLebeau. You solved my question.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`TStringGrid.Cells`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid.Cells) property to read the individual columns, and use the [`TStringGrid.Row`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid.Row) property to know which row is selected.

```
var row: integer;
...
row := StringGrid1.Row;
Edit1.Text := StringGrid1.Cells[0,row];
Edit2.Text := StringGrid1.Cells[1,row];
```